# Get values from Array with event.Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, pdf

So I'm dealing with the following.

I'm creating a PDF and let the user fill in fields.
One of the fields is a list. Upon selection other fields are filled with fitting content.

This content is stored within an array.

So this is what I did:

```
var company = ["comapny name", "street", "Postcode", "City", "Country"];
var company1 = ["comapny name1", "street1", "Postcode1", "City1", "Country1"];
if (!event.willCommit){ 
    if (listCompany.value == "comapny name"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = company[2];
    }
    if (listCompany.value == "comapny name1"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = company1[2];
    }
}
```

The above part does not give an error but gives me the "previous" content.
The PDF loads and then fields are filled. Upon change of list the fields won't change their content. Only after the second click.

So I found the following:
`event.changeEx;`

After a simple try it works great:

```
var company = ["comapny name", "street", "Postcode", "City", "Country"];
var company1 = ["comapny name1", "street1", "Postcode1", "City1", "Country1"];
if (!event.willCommit){ 
    if (listCompany.value == "comapny name"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = event.changeEx;
    }
    if (listCompany.value == "comapny name1"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = event.changeEx;
    }
}
```

This gives me the value of the selected item. But the problem I'm having now is how to select the other fields from my array based upon the selection.

Comment: could you please add a working fiddle or snippet of your code

Comment: This is the code... Like I said it's a PDF that contains fields. Fields have an `id` containing the name listed after `getField`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it after a lot of googling.

The `event.changeEx` works on comboboxes and takes the value of the change.
This means that this is updated as soon as the selection changes.

Which can result in the following:

```
var company = ["comapny name", "street", "Postcode", "City", "Country"];
var company1 = ["comapny name1", "street1", "Postcode1", "City1", "Country1"];
if (!event.willCommit){ 
    if (event.changeEx == "comapny name"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = company[1];
    }
    if (event.changeEx == "comapny name1"){
        this.getField("fldStreet").value = company1[1];
    }
}
```

If the `event.changeEx` value equals the company name the array can be read.

Next step is to create some sort of loop because I'm not gonna do this for every company :-)

Comment: The next step would be done via a 2-dimensional array, where the elements of the first level/dimension are the company information. You will then be able to access the according company via its index in that array.

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes tried that but for some reason I couldn't get the values out so I decided to create objects. So basically I do the same :-) thnx for you reply tho!